# Do bees use their ovipositors for egg-laying?

Tags: bees

I'd always assumed that, since bee stings are 'modified ovipositors', queen bees couldn't sting. But apparently they can.

What is going on with bees' ovipositors? Are they capable of injecting both venom and eggs?

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is easy enough to google. Did you try, and if yes, what did you find? You might wonder what kind of Q&A site this is, being asked to show your search results; shouldn't we just answer your question? Actually, no. We're expected to help if we so choose. We're scientists or people interested in science, a lot of us teach, practice, or research some aspect of Biology. We expect some meaningful degree of research; not a ton, but not nothing, either. Consider this kind of like a classroom, not a chat room. You'll get a (better) response with a better effort on your part.

Comment: Googling didn't turn up anything useful for me, but if you know the magic phrase to google for, let me know, and I'll finish the research and answer the question myself!

Comment: Try some combination of your own words: ovipositors, stingers, queen bee, eggs.

Comment: So, from the first page of hits for "ovipositors, stingers, queen bee, eggs", I have : "However, in virtually all stinging Hymenoptera, the ovipositor is no longer used for egg-laying."  and "Queen bees can use their ovipositors to lay eggs and to sting but worker bees only use it to sting as they are infertile and don't lay eggs." That sort of thing is why I asked the damned question here, where I thought an actual biologist might answer it.

Comment: OK, so you think all Biologists know about queen bee ovipositors/stingers? An etymologist would probably know, or an apiarist. Don't know if we have either one on this site; I'd be surprised if we didn't have an apiarist or two. I have two advanced degrees in Biology, and I didn't know off the top of my head, but I did google it and found the answer. **You also found the answer**: your two statements are not mutually exclusive. Think about the statements and tell me why you think they don't answer your question, and I'll answer the damned question personally! ;)

Comment: So, if 'virtually all stinging hymenoptera' doesn't include the canonical example of stinging hymenoptera, then yes, clear. Queen bees lay eggs through their stingers. As implied by the unlikely conjunction of two random things on the internet. But the only reason I think that might be true now is because you've just elliptically told me this and you claim to have appropriate knowledge. I was hoping that someone might actually answer the question, maybe with a link to a trustworthy source. A man can dream. Don't worry, I won't be troubling your website with my half-wit questions again.

Comment: I'm not going to feel sorry for you for labeling your own question as "half-wit". Your feelings are what they are, and I have no control over that. It's not a bad question; hover over the downvote arrow and note that "contains no research" is a reason to DV  and to close. You were welcomed, up voted, no one down voted you, not even me. Think what you will. Btw, *virtually* is just shy of "all (full stop.)"

Comment: If you still want an answer, I will provide a definitive one tomorrow. It might surprise you to learn that even someone with two advanced degrees in Biology can be wrong. Maybe your question was better than your last assessment.